# Erro em campo numérico MVC Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Pessoal estou com problema no Asp.NET MVC quando uso campo numérico estou tendo erro. o Razor esta assim

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AliqIpi, new
{
    htmlAttributes = new {
        @class = "form-control", @style = "text-align: right;", @type = "number", @min = "0", @step = "0.01", @value = "0"
    }
})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AliqIpi, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

e ao editar o registro quando movo os valores para a grid não mostra os valores numéricos e da este erro

> The specified value "0,00" is not a valid number. The value must match
>   to the following regular expression:
>   -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Alguém já passou por isto?

Comment: o type number só aceita números, se você estiver tentando adicionar caracteres troque por `@type = "tel"`

Comment: é número mesmo, só que fica dando este erro.

Comment: Então, `,` não é número, troca o tipo pra `tel`